# IE 10 issue with jQuery modal form

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-10

Got one interesting problem with IE 10 and all older versions. 
I have a 
`<div id="modal_window"></div>`
in which I load a different php page in modal window with jQuery.
Code is like this:

```
  /* Open page in modal dialog */
  var dlg=$('#modal_window').dialog({
    title: 'Submit event report',
    resizable: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    hide: 'fade',
    width: 450,
    height: 275,
    open: function() {
      jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
        jQuery('#modal_window').dialog('close');
      });
    }
  });

  $('.edit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    dlg.load(href, function() {
      dlg.dialog('open');
    });
  });
```

So basicly on click I load in that div content from page, which I get here:

```
echo "<td><a href='sbmevent.php?id=".$row['event_id']."' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Here I'm passing to link an id which differs, the problem is that in IE when I output some content in some links when it opens it shows one of three different problems:

1. It outputs somehow id which is passed to link [image: List item]
2. Everything ok, what I expected [image: List item]
3. And just an empty file, which I don't understand why   [image: List item]

I have no idea what's the problem the code is the same for all windows, the ids are ok, in firefox and chrome everything working perfect..
Any Ideas? 
PHP code is simple:

```
    if (isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $event_id = $_GET['id'];
        $q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `'.TABLE_PREFIX.'events` WHERE `event_id` = '.$event_id);
        if ($q) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Study Nr.</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo "xxx"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Centre Nr.</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['centre']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Doctor</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['doctor']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Category</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo "xxx"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Venue/Location</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['city_id']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Contact/Sponsor</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['sponsor']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> 
<?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you resolved this one yet? If you look in the developer tools can you confirm that HTML is being returned via your AJAX request. I'm wondering if it might be an htmlentities issue. If the data coming out of the database has the potential to contain quotes or < > characters then when IE tries to render the form it can get confused by misformed HTML.

Comment: Yes, thank you for interesting. Problem was from different js file which somehow was changing this dialog box behavior in IE. Exact reason I didn't found because there was a lot of code in js and I'm too weak yet in js. But after removing this file it worked well.